# Evaluation of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given$$ f(x) = \frac{2^x }{2^x +\sqrt{2}}$$
Then find $$S_n= \sum^{2n-1} _{r=1} 2f(\frac{r}{2n})$$
So I tried to evaluate it by adding and subtracting a $√2$ term from numerator , but it didn't help , I tried to take something common,but it was no help either. I don't think so any formula is applicable here...

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$ (try proving this!) so your sum becomes $2(n-1+f(\frac{1}{2}))$, which is just $2(n-1+\frac{1}{2})$, or $2n-1$.